# Is the Main Function of a Class Called When an Object of That Class is Created?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a WinForms project in Visual Studio, and I have a class in a separate file which has a Main function that runs a console application.

Now, I want to either run this Main function of my separate class, or create a different function to run this code. Does creating an object of a class automatically run the `Main()` function of that class? Or will the Main() function only run if that particular file is the main file you are running your code from?

Comment: Wow, people come here just to dislike  the question. This is NOT a duplicate or obvious question. I don't understand any reason that it should be disliked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The code that runs automatically when you create a class is in the constructor, which is a method that has a name the same as the class (and no return type)

```
public class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
    //this is the constructor. Code here is run automatically when you make a new MyClass
  }
}
```

Applications typically have a Main() somewhere, and it is called automatically when the app starts, but that is the only time it is called automatically and only one of the classes in the program has a main that is called automatically.

In other words, you can have as many classes (each with Main methods) as you like but you'll have to call them manually from your code if you want them to run

```
class Program{
  static void Main(string[] args){
    //this method will be called automatically to kick start your code running if..
    //it is configured in the project properties that Program shall be the startup object
  }
}
class MyClass{
  static void Main(string[] args){
    //this is also a method called main, but this one won't be called automatically, ever, 
    //if the project's Startup Object is set to Program
  }
}
```

If you have multiple classes with a Main you can choose which one will be called upon startup, in the project settings:

[image]

But from there on after if you have another class with a Main you have to call it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I would say that [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args) are pretty clear:

- The `Main` method is the entry point of an executable program; it is where the program control starts and ends.
- `Main` is declared inside a class or struct. Main must be static and it need not be public. (In the earlier example, it receives the default access of private.) The enclosing class or struct is not required to be static.

So the `Main` method should be [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) thus no object creation needed to call it. When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked, basically meaning that it will be run for you and you don't need to run it manually.

Other then that it is an ordinary C# function which can be invoked from your code (though not sure why you will want to do something like this):

```
private static bool x = true;
static void Main()
{
    if(x)
    {
        x = !x; // without this you will get "infinite" reqursion resulting in SO
        Main();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```